# Topshelf installer requires me to press enter twice - why?

Tags: topshelf

When installing af service through cmd.exe the installer requires interaction with the command prompt. Twice i have to press a key to get it to continue.
This is a problem for me when I want to automate the install.

```
c:\>MyService.exe install
Configuration Result:
[Success] Name SFTP_Service
[Success] DisplayName SFTP Service
[Success] Description SFTP Service
[Success] ServiceName SFTP_Service
Topshelf v3.1.118.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.17929

Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
Installing SFTP Service service
```

**At this point interaction is required**

```
Installing service SFTP_Service...
Service SFTP_Service has been successfully installed.
Creating EventLog source SFTP_Service in log Application...
```

**At this point interaction is required again**

```
The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.

The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.

c:\>
```

What can I do to make the installer continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facepalm!

This will happen if you have this in your HostFactory.Run()

```
x.BeforeInstall(() => Console.ReadKey());
x.AfterInstall(() => Console.ReadKey());
```