# Topshelf: install command does not return after successfully installing the service

Tags: c#, .net, topshelf

NOTE: I'm not doing anything similar to [Topshelf installer requires me to press enter twice - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19925979/190476)

Service class (interesting parts):

```
public class ServiceCore
{
    public ServiceCore(ServiceRuntimeConfiguration serviceRuntimeConfiguration)
    {
        _runningTasks = new List<Task>();
    }

        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            _hostControl = hostControl;
            _messageProcessor.Start(); // Starts a System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            StartListener(); // starts a System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            return true;
        }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
Host host = HostFactory.New(configurator =>
{

configurator.UseNLog();

// Configure core service
configurator.Service<ServiceCore>(svc =>
{
    svc.ConstructUsing(theService => new ServiceCore(_serviceRuntimeConfiguration));
    svc.WhenStarted((svc, hostControl) => svc.Start(hostControl));
    svc.WhenStopped((svc, hostControl) => svc.Stop(hostControl));
});

// Configure recovery params
configurator.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryConfigurator =>
{
    recoveryConfigurator.RestartService(0);
    recoveryConfigurator.OnCrashOnly();
    recoveryConfigurator.SetResetPeriod(1);
});

// Execute HostConfigurator
host.Run();
}
```

**The Problem**

When I do this:

```
MyService.exe install --manual --localsystem
```

The service installs fine, but the command never returns:

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. Installing service
>   NotificationEngine.Main... Service NotificationEngine.Main has been
>   successfully installed.
>
> The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is
>   beginning.
>
> The Commit phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.
>
> ^C (I have to press CTRL+C)

What should I do for the install command to complete and then return?

**NOTE** The same behaviour is observable if I run help (i.e. help displays but the command does not return):

```
MyService.exe help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this means you don't release control of some resource and the process can't cleanly exit. However, this stuff is complicated, so it's hard to say for sure.

A few things I would try

- What happens when you execute `MyService start` after an install/CTRL+C? I'm assuming it also blocks since help does.
- Check logging, do you have any enabled? Is there file contention or permissions issues?
- What else does your `Main()` entry point do? Is it doing something that after `host.Run()`? Your code above makes it looks like you're calling it from within the construction of that object, but I assume it's bad cut-n-pasting.
- Make sure you aren't initializing resources before the `ConstructUsing` and `When*` callbacks are fired.

After this, I would take this to our mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topshelf-discuss.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I'll check and post back.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceCore : ServiceBase

The type T specified in the configurator.Service should subclass ServiceBase.

This fixed the problem for a service that would install fine but hang on the last step of install/uninstall.